# How to change Microsoft account email in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, email, user-accounts

I have changed my email and I want to link my Microsoft account to this new email so I can login with this email to Windows 8.1. How can I do this either online or in Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

Go to this url [live account settings](https://account.live.com/) and login.
Click 'Manage aliases' and add your new e-mail adress. Once added and verified you can set that email adress as your primary and optionally remove the old email adress.

Comment: This solution does not work if I want my Windows' logon screen displaying my new adress. I have a Microsoft account on my Win 8.1. I changed my email adress and want to display the new one on the logon screen. I already changed the adress on my online Microsoft account and deleted the old one, but that doesn't changed anything on the logon screen.

Comment: In fact, it does work, but I had to wait several hours before my logon screen updates accordingly.